# Are the PostScript Type 1, 2, or 14 font formats still alive?

Tags: fonts, postscript

It seems that all the default fonts in my copy of Windows 7 are in [TrueType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueType) or [OpenType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenType) formats. Is the [PostScript Type 1 font format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts#Type_1) still alive? And do we still use the PostScript [Type 2 ( CFF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts#Type_2) or [Type 14 (chameleon)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript_fonts#Type_14) font formats?

Comment: off-topic or not, this question is found through google, so and answer is valuable: Type 1 and Type 14 are obsolete and no longer in use or endorsed. Type 2, on the other hand, is the charstring format of choice for OpenType with a CFF table (conventionally, fonts with the `.otf` extension, as opposed to `.ttf` fonts, which are still OpenType fonts, but use TrueType tables). At the time of this comment, Adobe's *entire* fonts catalogue is OpenType/CFF, and many advanced fonts use Type2 because it allows subroutines, including complex postscript transforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chameleon is patented and specific to Adobe, and was never popular, it is dead. Type 1 fonts are still available, but most new fonts are being created in OpenType format, either with TrueType or CFF outlines.

Comment: In addition to what @KenS said, they did finally change the installation method of PostScript fonts in Windows 7, possibly Vista, too. Instead of going to `%WINDIR%\Fonts`, and selecting "Install New Font" from the File menu, you now can just right-click the "pfm" file and select Install.